# How do I set the mat-slide-toggle state before page loads?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a component that sets user access for available posts. 
It loads up the posts, selected user and the toggle in a mat-table. When I select the toggle to checked it adds a string (postId) to my firestore user doc posts array. When I uncheck it, it removes the postId from the array.

However when I close the component and open it again, the toggle state is lost for each post.

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <mat-slide-toggle  (change)="changed(row, $event)" >Access</mat-slide-toggle>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
```

```
  changed(post, e: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    if (e.checked === true) {
      this.auth.grantPostAccess(this.selectedUser, post.id);
    } else {
      this.auth.removePostAccess(this.selectedUser, post.id);
    }
  }
```

I want to be able to set the state of the toggle to true if the postId exists in my string array. This should happen before the component loads.

Comment: using the binding  [checked]="checked" where checked is a value referenced from your component

Comment: Thanks Pari! How do I use a method in the checked binding [checked]="postExists(postId)"?

Comment: yes a function that returns true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain predefined properties included in elements using these you can check or uncheck an element in your case:

```js
 [checked]="postExists(selectedUser, row.id)"
```